# [Electron][OSX] Always show the tray icon

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, operating-system, electron

I am writing an OSX App using Electron,
and it primarily focuses on the tray. Basically, it only shows when the app is currently being used, how can I set it so that its independant to the window?

Answer (score 2):

You can just create your tray in main process and don't create a window.

```
const {app, Menu, Tray} = require('electron')

let tray = null
app.on('ready', () => {
  tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {label: 'Item1', type: 'radio'},
    {label: 'Item2', type: 'radio'},
    {label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true},
    {label: 'Item4', type: 'radio'}
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
})
```